# measurement widget area value display in the textbox

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api

is there any way that measurement widget area value display in a textbox.

```
 var measurement = new esri.dijit.Measurement({
      map: map
    }, dojo.byId('measurementDiv'));
    measurement.startup();
  var meswidget = dijit.byId('Area');
      meswidget.set("value", measurement);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen for the `measure-end` event.
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/measurement-amd.html#event-measure-end

```
measurement.on("measure-end", function(evt) {
    console.log(evt.toolName + ": " + evt.values + " " + evt.unitName);
});
```

The event has the exact value, so you'll probably want to do some rounding for display.

Comment: thanks it gets value but i do not how to show this value in the text box

Comment: var area = console.log(e.toolName + ": " + e.values + " " + e.unitName);
      dijit.byId("Area").innerHTML = area.toFixed(2);

Comment: measurement.on("measure-end", function(e) {
  var area = e.values;
      document.getElementById("Area").innerHTML = area.toFixed(2);
    
       }); it doesnot show value in the textbox

Comment: Does your "Area" element exist? Does the browser console show any type of error?